# Open 2 Adjacent UDP Ephemeral Ports

Tags: c++, network-programming

How might it be possible to write a function which opens two adjacent ports. For instance, the first time it might take ports 1234 and 1235, the next call might take 5678 and 5677 and so on.

The problem I have is that if I take an ephemeral port first, I can't guarantee that either of the adjacent ports are taken or not. So the solution would be to take an ephemeral port in a loop, continuously trying to take an adjacent port until one is found.

Taking a random port has the same problem as the ephemeral port.

If I continuously add one trying to take ports, where do I stop and start and when do I stop searching?

Is there a quick way to test if two ports are open, preferably without having to open them first. I would rather have an operating system independent solution, however if I have to write a solution for each OS, that's fine.

Comment: "Test if two ports are open without actually opening them" is not a solution; it's a race condition.

Comment: Good point. Does that mean the best solution can be to open ports and keep trying, maybe giving up after 50 tries or so?

Comment: You have to open the ports and try opening neighbors.  The only thing you can really "optimize" is whether you get the first of each pair from the OS, or randomly select it yourself.  Also, whether you close the "boxed-in" ports before trying more, or keep them open so the OS can't give you the same exact number right back again.

Comment: All good points, thanks for the help. I'll leave this question up in the hope someone can give more knowledge on the subject. I will likely answer the question myself when I have a full solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the operating system opens the next available port as an ephemeral port when you open a socket and connect to a server or send a UDP datagram. However, you cannot trust this and this depends on many factors including other applications opening sockets, OS implementation, etc.

If you want to open adjacent sockets you need to bind a socket before sending the datagram.

Code would be something like this:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>

...

int main() {
    int ret;
    int fd[65536];
    struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
    uint16_t port = 10000;


    for(int i = 1; i < 65536; i++)
    {
        fd[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if (fd[i] < 0) exit(1);

        // Local
        memset(&myaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        myaddr.sin_port = htons(i);
        myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(MY_IP_ADDRESS);

        ret = bind(fd[i], (struct sockaddr *)&myaddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

        ...
    }

    ...
    return 0;   
}
```